# When / how frequently do miners get paid for transaction fees?

Tags: transaction-fees, mining-reward, coinbase-transaction

When or how frequently do miners get paid for transaction fees?

Comment: This seems like a subset of this question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9895/who-gets-bitcoin-transaction-fees

Comment: @NickODell The selected answer says "The fee goes to the miner who mines the block that includes your transaction." So, the miner gets it right away, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With every block the successful mining entity reaps all the included transaction's fees. So, in the case of solo mining, a miner gets paid transaction fees every time he finds a block, in the case of a mining pool a miner's payouts depend on the mining pool's policies.