# Bitcoin Core 17.0 - How to calculate balance with zero confirmations included (watch-only)?

Tags: bitcoin-core, balance, watch-only

Is it currently possible to calculate balance including UTXOs with 0 confirmations, for watch-only addresses?

```
getbalance "*" 0 true
```

includes utxos with 0 confirmations only if that address has private key in the wallet. Balance from watch-only addresses is added when corresponding UTXOs have at least 1 conf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Bitcoind requires at least 1 confirmation before a utxo amount is added to your watch-only address balance. Which makes sense, as it can still be trivially double-spent whilst it is not yet confirmed.

**Related question:** [bitcoind sendfrom with minconf=0](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/42577/bitcoind-sendfrom-with-minconf-0)

Comment: Thanks! If I want that feature, I could implement it by using "listunspent 0", and summing amounts, am I right?