# Does the NBitcoin library internally use blockchain.info to process transactions?

Tags: transaction-fees, blockchain.info, mining-reward

My concern is about miner's fee, who is taking that amount? Blockchain.info or `NBitcoin`? I just wanted to confirm whether the library internally uses blockchain.info apis for performing transactions.

Comment: Are you referring to the .NET library NBitcoin (https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin), or something else?  Your question is very unclear what it is asking.

Comment: Yes, I m talking about .Net Library NBitcoin. I just wanted to confirm whether this framework internally uses blockchain apis for performing transactions.

Comment: By blockchain, do you mean the bitcoin blockchain (the distributed ledger), or the commercial service blockchain.info?

Comment: I meant Commercial service blockchain.info

Comment: Please edit your question to include the information you provided in the comments to clarify it.

Comment: I've edited the question to add the information from the comments. However, the question appears to grow from a misunderstanding: libraries and wallet services cannot collect transaction fees. [It's always the miners that get the fee.](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9895/5406)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, NBitcoin does not use Blockchain.info's API in order to interact with the Bitcoin blockchain.  It implmenents the Bitcoin scripting language, network protocol, transaction construction, and other aspects.  This allows programmers to use NBitcoin to directly interact with the Bitcoin network.

Since transaction construction is in the hands of the NBitcoin user, transactions can be constructed with whatever miner fees you choose.